# Looping through folders to read shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, geodataframe

I would like to adapt a function, that reads many shapefiles in *one* specific folder, to read many shapefiles in *many* folders.

Here is the function that reads multiple shapefiles in ONE folder.

```
def import_shapes_list(path_to_data:str,shapes_folder:str,crs:str,current_crs:str) ->gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """
    """
    files = glob.iglob(path_+'*.shp')
    
    gdfs = []
    for file in files:
        print(file)            
        gdf = read_gdf(file,crs,current_crs=current_crs)
        gdf.columns = map(str.lower, gdf.columns)        
        gdfs.append(gdf)
        
   
    geomap = gpd.GeoDataFrame( pd.concat( gdfs, ignore_index=True) )   
    
    return geomap 

geomap_nord=import_shapes_list(path_to_data=path_to_data,shapes_folder=shapes_folder_nord, crs='EPSG:4326',current_crs='EPSG:26191')
```

The output is this:

```
./Source data/...../shapefile1.shp
./Source data/...../shapefile2.shp
./Source data/...../shapefile3.shp
```

I have tried to adapt it so that it loops through multiple folders. Here is what I have tried:

```
import os
path_to_data = './Source data/'  
rootdir = path_to_data + '...2021/'
files = glob.iglob(rootdir+'*.shp')    
gdfs = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:           
       print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

the output is:

```
folder1/xxxx.cpg
folder1/xxxx.dbf
folder1/xxxx.prj
folder1/xxxx.qmd
folder1/xxxx.shp
folder1/xxxx.shx
folder2/yyyy.cpg
folder2/yyyy.dbf
folder2/yyyy.prj
folder2/yyyy.shp
```

My issue is that it reads everything inside each folder when it should be reading only shapefiles.

How can I adapt the function above to make it read the shapefiles inside each folder?

Comment: It is a pure Python problem. Simply add `if file.endswith('.shp'):` in the for loop  (files defined twice with glob and in the loop)

Comment: Would you mind answering with the full code please?

Answer (score 1):

I have generated this work which works.

```
files = glob.iglob(rootdir+ '*.shp')
print('rootdir is', rootdir)
gdfs = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            print('file is', file)            
            path_to=os.path.join(subdir, file)
            gdf = read_gdf(path_to, crs,current_crs=current_crs)
            gdf.columns = map(str.lower, gdf.columns)        
            gdfs.append(gdf)

file is x.shp
file is y.shp
file is z.shp
file is aa.shp
file is ab.shp
file is ab.shp
file is ac.shp
file is ad.shp
file is ae.shp
file is af.shp
file is az.shp
```

The code works and reads through every folder but is there a better way to write it? I don't feel that this is optimal as it is taking a long time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an ancient Python version, this should be ideal:

```
rootdir = ...
gdfs = []
for file in Path(rootdir).rglob("*.shp"):
    print('file is', file)            
    gdf = read_gdf(file, crs,current_crs=current_crs)
    gdf.columns = map(str.lower, gdf.columns)        
    gdfs.append(gdf)
```

Be aware that your file-system might be case-sensitive, usually this is the case on Linux.